# Alpine Linux & Custom Certificate Authorities

Tags: wget, certificates, alpine-linux

I've been trying to install a custom CA into some Alpine Linux container.

First I would add the public key in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`, then run `update-ca-certificates`.

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
total 4
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          2029 Feb 20 18:39 my-custom-ca.crt
$ update-ca-certificates
...

$ ls -ltr /etc/ssl/certs | tail -3
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     root        233441 Feb 20 18:52 ca-certificates.crt
lrwxrwxrwx    1 1000     root            49 Feb 20 18:52 ca-cert-my-custom-ca.pem -> /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/my-custom-ca.crt
lrwxrwxrwx    1 1000     root            24 Feb 20 18:52 51252b35.0 -> ca-cert-my-custom-ca.pem
```

Yet this does not seem to work completely.

Sure, I can confirm the certificate is trusted by OpenSSL:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect <my-server-crt-cn>:443 -showcerts 
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = FR, ST = France, L = Paris, O = x, OU = y, CN = <my-ca-name>
verify return:1
depth=0 C = FR, ST = France, L = Paris, O = x, OU = y, CN = <my-server-crt-cn>
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = FR, ST = France, L = Paris, O = x, OU = y, CN = <my-server-crt-cn>
   i:C = FR, ST = France, L = Paris, O = x, OU = y, CN = <my-ca-name>
...

    Start Time: 1613847660
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
```

Yet, other tools such as wget, or the ruby app I'm trying to run, do not seem to care:

```
$ wget https://<my-server-crt-cn>/
ssl_client: <my-server-crt-cn>: certificate verification failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain
wget: error getting response: Connection reset by peer

$ wget --no-check-certificate https://<my-server-crt-cn> -O-
Connecting to <my-server-crt-cn> (10.42.253.168:443)
writing to stdout
<response>
<returncode>SUCCESS</returncode>
<version>2.0</version>
```

I can reproduce building the following image:

```
FROM docker.io/alpine:3.11
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    ca-certificates \
    openssl
COPY my-ca.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
```

Testing on my workstation (Debian), I have no troubles at all, once the CA is trusted I can use wget/curl without ignoring tls errors.

Did I do something wrong? Why would wget or ruby keep complaining about my certificate being self-signed?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, my issue lies with the wget shipping with Apline.

By default, Alpine comes with a wget from busybox:

```
/ $ wget --version
wget: unrecognized option: version
BusyBox v1.31.1 () multi-call binary.
```

If I patch my Dockerfile to install wget, alongside ca-certificates, then I can connect without warning nor skipping certificates verification.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's because *busybox* `wget` in Alpine Linux is patched to require external executable `ssl_client` which handles HTTPS, see https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/commit/1d0560a9b6b5597b191e5aff69a31c2fe0aba273